# http latency wild variance on localhost

Tags: linux, performance, ping, real-time, latency

Running on MBP M1 with 10 cores.
Running 1 thread client (wrk) and 1 thread server (java).
A youtube is also running on the system.
Load average 2 out of 10.
Except GC, which could be the reasons of the wild variance in latency below?

```
            "percentile": 0,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 10
        },
        {
            "percentile": 50,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 16
        },
        {
            "percentile": 99,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 51
        },
        {
            "percentile": 99.9,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 1500
        },
        {
            "percentile": 99.99,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 9598
        },
        {
            "percentile": 99.999,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 15021
        }
```

The same variance happens when using nginx, or a rust web server.
The same on the M1, in a Linux docker, or on a Linux EC2 machine.
What could cause such a huge variation from 10 microseconds to 15 milliseconds?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly your latency figures relate to (what measurement), could you also provide the reasons that motivate the *real-time* tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if i do epoll/select every 5 ms, the upper bound becomes a little bit lower.

```
wrk -d2134 -t2 -c10 http://127.0.0.1:8089 -s script.lua               took  17s at  10:14:19
Running 36m test @ http://127.0.0.1:8089
  2 threads and 10 connections
^C  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    40.98us   18.24us   3.62ms   80.67%
    Req/Sec   109.03k     3.86k  115.50k    68.43%
  24368820 requests in 1.87m, 1.72GB read
Requests/sec: 216998.38
Transfer/sec:     15.73MB

JSON Output:
{
    "requests": 24368820,
    "duration_in_microseconds": 112299548.00,
    "bytes": 1852030320,
    "requests_per_sec": 216998.38,
    "bytes_transfer_per_sec": 16491876.89,
    "latency_distribution": [
        {
            "percentile": 0,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 10
        },
        {
            "percentile": 90,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 61
        },
        {
            "percentile": 99,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 88
        },
        {
            "percentile": 99.5,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 95
        },
        {
            "percentile": 99.9,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 117
        },
        {
            "percentile": 99.95,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 128
        },
        {
            "percentile": 99.99,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 230
        },
        {
            "percentile": 99.999,
            "latency_in_microseconds": 1803
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just great if playing with the thermometer makes you feel better. I can't unfortunately share your happiness since I fail to understand how this post answers your question and still cannot figure out the answer to the questions asked in OP's comment. (Particularly regarding real-time.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).